# error when trying to programatically build connection string for EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I am using EF ver 6 and I am trying to build my connection string programatically as follows:

```
public GlContext() : base(ConnectionString()) { }
private static string ConnectionString()
{
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new sqlConnectionStringBuilder();
 sqlBuilder.DataSource = "myserver";
 sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "GLPROD";
 sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
 sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
 sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
 sqlBuilder.UserID = "user";
 sqlBuilder.Password = "pwd";
 sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework";

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new       EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

        return entityBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

When trying to use `GlContext` I get this error:

> keyword not supported: 'provider'

I have spent hours trying to figure out why this code would not work... if I load it from `app.config` then it works well. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` mutually exclusive to `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`? i.e. just return `sqlBuilder.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

`EntityConnectionStringBuilder` should be used for EDMX model and for Code First model (DbContext based ones) you should use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.